# Dependency Challenge with CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, perl, dependencies

Given the following output, suggestions on what to try first? This is on a CentOS 5.3 box (upgraded from 5.2 via yum) running as a little dev server. I'm generally comfortable with *nix, but dependency chasing leaves me a bit perplexed at times. So this time I'm seeking help before I run amuck.

Output from today's "yum update":

```
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Net-SSLeay.i386 0:1.35-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-IO-Socket-SSL.noarch 0:1.26-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-Net-DNS.i386 0:0.65-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-Package-Constants.noarch 0:0.02-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.020-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) >= 2.020 for package: perl-IO-Compress
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020 for package: perl-IO-Compress
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.i386 0:2.015-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.020-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020 for package: perl-IO-Compress
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
perl-IO-Compress-2.020-1.el5.rf.noarch from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020 is needed by package perl-IO-Compress-2.020-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020 is needed by package perl-IO-Compress-2.020-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
```

**perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib)** is a package name?!? If so, I get this on an update attempt:

```
Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.015-1.el5.rf.i386 already installed and latest version
```

Wrong version, yet says it is the latest...

Just in case this is helpful:

```
$ uname -a
Linux EFhermesDev 2.6.18-128.1.16.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Wed Jul 1 13:06:47 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are seeing an rpmforge dependency problem, *not* a CentOS dependency problem.

rpmforge perl modules are mass rebuilt at the moment. See http://lists.rpmforge.net/pipermail/users/2009-July/002508.html ff.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. So maybe I just wait a day or two then?

Answer (score 3):

Note that from CentOS-5.3 onwards you can try:

```
   yum update --skip-broken
```

...this will likely work even better in 5.4.

Comment: Great tip! I wasn't aware of that option. Ironically, I'm in a similar situation again... I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This seems to still not be fixed in RPMForge. I tried enabling rpmforge-extras but the issue seems to be the perl-IO-Compress wants noarch packages but the perl-Compress packages are all arch specific.. Anyway, running with --skip-broken worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can get version 2.020 [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Compress/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.020.tar.gz) ([readme](http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Compress/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.020.readme)).  It was released June 3, 2009.

### Background:

The dependency is calling for a newer version than your repository thinks is the newest version:

```
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020 is needed by package perl-IO-Compress-2.020-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
```

You have an older version installed than the dependency calls for:

```
Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.015-1.el5.rf.i386 already installed and latest version
```

As it says, you need to install:

```
perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.020
```

in order to resolve this dependency.

Comment: right. I have 2.015 and it wants 2.020. yum update for that gives the output I listed above ("already installed and latest version").

Thus my question here :-)

Comment: edited to provide a link to the depended-upon version.. =)

Answer (score 2):

That's because the repository you are using is out of sync with itself.

[Browse this site.](http://packages.sw.be/)

As of this post, the perl-IO-Compress.noarch package was updated to 2.020 and it depends on a 2.020 version of perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.

However, the perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib is still at 2.015.
You can wait till they catch up or you can ignore perl-IO-Compress.noarch in yum till then.

Try adding:

```
exclude=perl-IO-Compress*
```

to /etc/yum.conf. (Haven't tested this, you may have to add other excludes, Try this from the command line and see what happens before adding to yum.conf)

You should be using the [EPEL repo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for things like this as far as possible. EPEL is a Fedora sub project and has higher standards.

Try to remove any rpmforge packages (and the yum repository) and use EPEL only.

Answer (score 0):

The "exclude=perl-IO-Compress*" statement does not work. The yum upgrade gets past this problem but encounters this problem later.

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Base::Common) >= 2.015 is needed by package perl-Compress-Zlib
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) >= 2.015 is needed by package perl-Compress-Zlib
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Gzip) >= 2.015 is needed by package perl-Compress-Zlib
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Gzip::Constants) >= 2.015 is needed by package perl-Compress-Zlib

Answer (score 0):

[solved] 
I'm trying (what a fool I was, just yesterday ;-) )

rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm

yum update

as they have the version 2.020 of perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib)

alexx

p.s. Zaph was right - this was the wrong way to go, (but I got there in the end with zero emails lost and zero downtime for my web servers.)

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: Not with that, but 
 yum erase  perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib
 yum -y update
worked (ish)
The erase took other things with it that I had to reinstall, (your list will probably not match mine, but here is mine for comparison.)
 yum -y install  munin-node perl-libwww-perl spamassassin
also I had to:
 srvadmin-services.sh  start
after the yum -y update
(Thanks http://serverfault.com/users/1936/chrisk for the confidence - I didn't really want to take a chance with my production server.)
Sadly omreport (Dell OpenManage) has stopped working, but I'll look into that and report back.

Comment: omreport now spits out
/etc/delloma.d/oma/bin/omcliproxy: error while loading shared libraries: libdsupt32.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
so I've fixed the yum update issue and now can't see if my server is over heating, (or if the data centre is too hot)

Comment: To test I did: 
<pre>ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libdsupt32.so.1.100.276 /usr/lib/libdsupt32.so.1
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libomacs32.so.1 /usr/lib/libomacs32.so.1
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libomclpr32.so.3 /usr/lib/libomclpr32.so.3
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libomcldb32.so.3.70.276 /usr/lib/libomcldb32.so.3
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libomclpr32.so.3 /usr/lib/libomclpr32.so.3
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libomadb32.so.3 /usr/lib/libomadb32.so.3
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/libxmlsup32.so.2 /usr/lib/libxmlsup32.so.2
</pre>

Comment: Now omreport works but
omreport chassis temps gives nothing and
omreport -? gives
Error! User has insufficient privileges to run command. (even as root)

Comment: \o/ [solved] with echo '/opt/dell/srvadmin/oma/bin/'>>/etc/ld.so.conf.d/omsa.conf ; ldconfig ; srvadmin-services.sh restart

(thanks to Rainer Traut over on http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2009-July/039640.html )
(before I found that I reinstalled the dell repo and srvadmin-all)

Answer (score 0):

Eek, don't change your repo just based on this one dependency error, they will fix it. Just be a little patient. Changing to the EPEL repo can cause other issues that may need to be fixed along the way, as they have different packages/builds/dependencies and if you are geared for RPMForge then you may need to change some packages to suit EPEL. So you are just swapping one issue for another.

Comment: Agreed! 

I did make a note, however, to give EPEL a closer look when I build my next CentOS server.

Answer (score 0):

How I got it to work.  I individually yum installed all the packages, one at a time.  The only one that didn't go was the perl-IO-Compress.
I went to http://packages.sw.be from above link, and downloaded the perl-IO-Compress-2.020-2/el5.rf.noarch.rpm (I am running RHEL 5.3) to a seperate directory.  I then ran yum install *.rpm from that directory.  It installed with no problem!!!  Also, my application still works.

Comment: I noticed perl-IO-Compress came down fine later in the day yesterday, so it looks like they got that one sorted out as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Centos 5.5. perl-IO-Compress is in rpmforge-extras now. Upgrade package rpmforge-release first:

yum update rpmforge-release

Merge new info from /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo.rpmnew into /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo. Now update using:

yum --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras upgrade